# Numerical integration with infinity as upper bound

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Verify:

$$y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = e^\frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int_\frac{1}{2}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{te^t} ≈ 0.9232.$$

I've written the integral as:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \displaystyle\int_\frac{1}{2}^x \frac{dt}{te^t}$$

I presume I should use substitution to continue but not sure why or how.

We have gone over Trapezoidal and Simpson's Rule for numerical integration so I presume that's what I should use to solve it

Comment: the solution containes the Gamma function

Comment: What is exactly what you can use?... and what is exactly your question?

Comment: @Miguel We have gone over Trapezoidal and Simpsons rule but none of the examples were close to this one. Well the exercise  was to Verify the integral and I'm not really sure how to

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\int_{12}^{\infty} \frac{1}{te^t} \, dt &\le \sum_{n = 12}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ne^n} \\
&\le \frac 1 {12e^{12}} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {e^n} \\
&< \frac{1}{e^{12}} \\
&< 0.000006
\end{align*}

is already small enough that it won't affect your computation's first four decimal places. Now just compute $\int_{1/2}^{12}$ using your favorite numerical method. (And by the way, this was a very crude method of estimate, so $12$ is a very loose upper bound.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the boundary does not enclose zero, change the integral variable $x=\frac{1}{t}$. Then the better method will be Gaussian quadratures to solve the integral numerically.

Assume $x=1/t$ then the integral becomes

$$\int_0^2\dfrac{e^{-1/x}}{x}dx$$

then standardize it by defining $x=z+1$ the integral becomes

$$I = \int_{-1}^1F(z)dz=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{e^{-1/(z+1)}}{z+1}dz$$

you may use any Gauss-Legendre formula via

$$I=\sum_{i=0}^nw_iF(z_i)$$

For four-point formula when $n=3$,

$$I=0.5590$$

if you multiply it by $e^{1/2}$, your final value is 0.9216.

Answer (score 1):

You substitute $u=\dfrac{1}{t}$

$dt = -\dfrac{du}{u^2}$

and get

$$\sqrt{e} \int_2^0 \frac{(-1) u}{e^{1/u} u^2} \, du=\sqrt{e} \int_0^2 \frac{e^{-1/u}}{u} \, du\approx 0.922911$$

[image]

Comment: why does the bounds change to 0 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution

$$
t = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{1-x}
$$

Note that when $x\to 1$ then $t\to\infty$. Your integral then becomes

$$
y(1/2) = -2e\int_0^{1}{\rm d}x~\frac{e^{1/(x-1)}}{x^2-1}
$$

The result is

$$
y(1/2)\approx 0.922911
$$

Comment: Not very useful answer... could you explain how you get the last line?

Comment: @Miguel The question was about the change of variables to do numerical integration. I assume the OP already has a method to carry out the latter.

Comment: Well, the fact is that the OP did not contain any question mark...

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\mathfrak{I}=e^{1/2}\int_{1/2}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x e^x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{\left(t+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)e^t}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\tfrac{1}{2}-\log u}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{v}{\tfrac{1}{4}-\log v}\,dv$$
where the last form is well-suited for standard techniques: the integration range is a bounded interval and the integrand function has bounded derivatives over the closed interval. For instance, through the trapezoidal rule:
$$ \mathfrak{I} \approx \frac{1}{100}\left[2+\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{\tfrac{k}{100}}{\tfrac{1}{4}-\log\tfrac{k}{100}}\right] \approx 0.923. $$